# What is happening step by step in this code to get the commented output?

Tags: javascript

userMsg = toUser("Bob") is calling toUser("Bob") and assigning it to userMsg which is then being concatenated with name and assigned to greet. So my brain is wanting to see greet = toUser("Bob") + name which is obviously not javascript is doing. What is going on with userMsg = toUser("Bob"); Is userMsg = message? or is userMsg = toUser("Bob");

Please help me to understand.
Why is this...

```
 function giveMessage(message) {
    
       let userMsg = message;
        userMsg = toUser("Bob");
        return userMsg;
        function toUser(userName) {
            let name = userName;
            let greet = userMsg + name;
            return greet;
        }
        
    }
    console.log(giveMessage("The world says hello dear: "));
// The world says hello dear: Bob
```

the same as this?

```
function giveMessage(message) {
    
       let userMsg = message;
        let hello = toUser("Bob");
        return hello;
        function toUser(userName) {
            let name = userName;
            let greet = userMsg + name;
            return greet;
        }
        
    }
    console.log(giveMessage("The world says hello dear: "));
// The world says hello dear: Bob
```

Comment: Please mention which output you are expecting

Comment: The output is commented out at the bottom as stated in the title. But I do not understand what is happening with userMsg = toUser("Bob") and why userMsg in let greet = userMsg + name is still using "The world says hello dear: " for userMsg after userMsg seemingly got reassigned to a different value in userMsg = toUser("Bob")

Comment: Google “devtools debugger”, it’s an invaluable skill to learn.

Comment: Just because the function appears after the code, does not mean that it runs after the code. The function definition is loaded first so that it can be used within that scope. `userMsg` will get re-assigned but first it needs to load the result from the function.

Comment: When you call the function, it uses the variable values _as they are at that time_. So when you **call** `toUser`, it will use the _current_ value of `userMsg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your first code snippet annotated with line numbers:

```
function giveMessage(message) {                          // line 1
                                                         // line 2
   let userMsg = message;                                // line 3
    userMsg = toUser("Bob");                             // line 4
    return userMsg;                                      // line 5
    function toUser(userName) {                          // line 6
        let name = userName;                             // line 7
        let greet = userMsg + name;                      // line 8
        return greet;                                    // line 9
    }                                                    // line 10
                                                         // line 11
}                                                        // line 12
console.log(giveMessage("The world says hello dear: ")); // line 13
```

The function `giveMessage` is defined starting on line 1, but is only invoked when it is called inside `console.log()` on line 13.

When it is invoked, the order of execution steps will be:

1. Execute line 3 (sets `userMsg` to the value of `message` which is `"The world says hello dear: "`)
2. Begin executing line 4, by evaluating the right hand side of the assignment expression (i.e. the call of function `toUser("Bob")`.
3. Execute line 7 (as part of the function call), and asign `name` to be the passed in value of `userName` which is `"Bob"`.
4. Execute line 8, which sets `greet` to the concatenated value of `userMsg` and `name`. Note that `userMsg` still holds the value that was assigned in step  1, since we are still only evaluating the right hand side of line 4. This means that `greet` gets set to `"The world says hello dear: " + "Bob"`.
5. The function returns he value of `greet`, and we jump back to line 4 to complete the assignment we began in step 2. Now we are setting `userMsg` and overwriting the value previously set in it, but that value was already used back in step 4, so we haven't lost anything.
6. Return the new value of `userMsg`.

Your second code snippet simply introduces a new variable to hold the output of the call to `toUser(...)`, and will have no effect on what happens inside `toUser(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Ergwun has already posted a good answer. I'd like to add just another angle to view the problem. You can simply "inline" the function to get an equivalent by replacing `return` with `userMsg =`. Hope this helps to clarify your doubt.

```js
function giveMessage(message) {
  let userMsg = message;
  // userMsg = toUser("Bob");
  // "inline" the `toUser` function:
  { 
    let userName = "Bob"; // toUser(userName = "Bob")
    let name = userName;
    let greet = userMsg + name;
    userMsg = greet;      // return greet;
  }
  return userMsg;
}

console.log(giveMessage("The world says hello dear: "));
```